# Perl split every n characters and new lines

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl. I know I can split some constant number of characters via `unpack` or using regexes.
But is there some standard way to split every n characters and new lines?

Here's the string I'm looking to split:

```
my $str="hello\nworld";
my $num_split_chars=2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str             = "hello\nworld";
my $num_split_chars = 2;
$num_split_chars--;

my @arr = $str =~ /.{$num_split_chars}.?/g;
print Dumper \@arr;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'he',
          'll',
          'o',
          'wo',
          'rl',
          'd'
        ];
```

Comment: Does perl actually store the entire regex in memory or some shortened form of it?

Comment: @simonzack - Do you mean the regex's results (the array) or the regex itself?  The regex is in memory.

Comment: The regex itself, I mean does perl expand it to a big `/................?/` first?

Comment: @simonzack - Given the value of `$num_split_chars`, the regex would be `/.{1}.?/g`

Comment: @ysth - Thank you for mentioning this quantifier limitation.

Comment: @Kenosis: Your way of catching the remaining chars does only work for groups of 2. What about `/.{1,$num_split_chars}/g` without decrementing?